# How can I open a wine program if there's no option to "open with"

Tags: wine

I have wine installed and I want to run `epsxe` but the "open with" isn't showing the wine program in the listing. What can I do?

Comment: You can go to the directory containing the .exe file ( via the "cd" terminal command or via "Open in Terminal" option found in some file managers like Nautilus) and type wine program.exe and hit enter to run it.

Answer (score 2):

You can go the directory containing the .exe file either via the `cd`(change directory) command , for example

```
cd .wine/drive_c/windows/
```

or just right-click the directory in your file manager and click `Open in Terminal` (most file managers like Dolphin or Nautilus have this option).

And then enter the name of the .exe program you want to execute for example

```
wine regedit.exe
```

all done !

Note : you necessarily don't have to `cd` into the desired directory , you can simply run

```
wine .wine/drive_c/windows/regedit.exe
```

Have fun using ubuntu ;)